# License Limit Exceeded Error while creating user

Tags: rest-api, customer-portal, user, licenses

I am facing **`License Limit Exceeded Exception`** when trying to insert a new user through Apex rest api class and error is given below

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, License Limit Exceeded: []

How can I avoid this exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no solution to this since you have consumed all the license that were allocated for your org .

Deactivate the existing users if you are testing your code .

You can also purchase additional license to avoid this .

Comment: Yeah......Mohith, I am thinking you are right.....

Comment: @KSKumaar - FYI... if you create a user within a Unit Test, then license limits are not considered. If you are testing code, then try to do it within an Apex Unit Test.